# Finding a vectorized solution for an aglortihm on a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, vectorization

This is my first post here, so hello to everyone!

I am working on a very large pandas DataFrame (8 million rows) and i need help on an operation i want to perform. My dataframe df has columns "Date" and "Customer Number".  Each row corresponds to a unique pair of these. Further, i have 5 dataframes called "active_12_2022", "active_01_2023", "active_02_2023", "active_03_2023" and "active_04_2023". Each of the "active" dataframes has a a column for customer number and a boolean column called "active".
My goal is to add an "active" column to df, where for each row we consider the month of the rows date and the previous month. If the customer is/has been active in of these two months, we set the active value in df to TRUE, otherwise to FALSE. If this data is not availiable (i.e. for each row in df, where the date is before 01/2023, we just take the two oldest DataFrames of active data availiale (i.e. active_12_2022 & active_01_2022).

I managed to do that with a small test dataframe using iterrows but on my orginal dataset the code has been running for over 4 hours now. Now I have read that you should avoid iterrows under all circumstances for performance reasons and look for a vectorized solution. However I don't know what this would mean in my case.

Hope you can help. Thank you!

Comment: Please show the code that you have and a sample of dataframe(s), i.e. provide a [mre].

Comment: how to ask a good question:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask